# Javascript recursive function to modify an object is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, recursion, mapping

All the texts for my app are inside a .json file for translation purposes. I need a function to get the corresponding text based on the selected language.

I think it should be an easy task, but I don't see the solution.

I have the following object:

```
{
  section1: {
    btn: { en: "English", es: "Español" },
    title: {
      en: "Web Frontend Developer",
      es: "Desarrollador Web de Frontend"
    },
    card: {
      title: { en: "Hello!", es: "Hola!" },
      btn: { en: "Get started", es: "Empecemos" },
    }
  }
}
```

This object should be passed to a function as the first parameter and the second parameter should be the language (in this case "en" or "es"). I want something like this: `filterObjByLanguage(obj, "es")`

And it should return:

```
{
  section1: {
    btn: "Español",
    title: "Desarrollador Web de Frontend",
    card: {
      title: "Hola!",
      btn: "Empecemos"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, it goes through each part of the object and wherever there is a `{ en:"text", es: "texto" }`, it chooses one of them based on the second parameter.

This is my attempt, but only the first layer of the object is returned correctly, the rest is undefined.

```
const filterObjByLanguage= (obj: any, lang: string): any => {
  const output = Object.assign(obj, {});

  const loop = (obj: any, isRoot: boolean = true): any => {
    for (var k in obj) {
      const value = output[k];
      const valueAtSelected = value?.[lang];

      if (typeof value === "string") {
        continue;
      } else if (valueAtSelected) {
        if (isRoot) output[k] = valueAtSelected;
        else return valueAtSelected;
      } else {
        if (isRoot) output[k] = loop(value, false);
        else return loop(value, false);
      }
    }
  };

  loop(output);

  return output;
};
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

There's one difficulty here: knowing what objects are language values versus which are collections of them.  In this solution, I use the existence of a `'en'` property as a signal.  Once we have that, it's mostly a matter of tearing apart and rebuilding objects using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`.  In plain JS (I'll leave Typescript for those who appreciate it!), it might look like this:

```js
const filterObjByLanguage = (lang) => (o) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? 'en' in o
      ? o [lang] || ''
      : Object .fromEntries (
          Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, filterObjByLanguage (lang) (v)])
        )
    : o

const i18n = {section1: {btn: {en: "English", es: "Español"}, title: {en: "Web Frontend Developer", es: "Desarrollador Web de Frontend"}, card: {title: {en: "Hello!", es: "Hola!"}, btn: {en: "Get started", es: "Empecemos"}}}}

console .log ('English', filterObjByLanguage ('en') (i18n))
console .log ('Español', filterObjByLanguage ('es') (i18n))
console .log ('Français', filterObjByLanguage ('fr') (i18n))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This also makes the decision that missing language values are simply empty strings.  If you prefer `undefined`, then you could just remove `|| ''`.  We can extend this to arrays if that's required with a simple modification:

```js
const filterObjByLanguage = (lang) => (o) =>
  Array .isArray (o) 
    ? o .map (filterObjByLanguage (lang)) 
  : Object (o) === o
    ? 'en' in o
      ? o [lang] || ''
      : Object .fromEntries (
          Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, filterObjByLanguage (lang) (v)])
        )
  : o
```